# Using r, how can I apply a function (moments::skewness) that is not a basic aggregate function to a group-by table?

Tags: r, dplyr, amazon-redshift

I have in Redshift a set of crowdsourced weather data:  many stations, each many days, each day 20 to 100 observations, each observation several variables.  I am computing daily statistics.  It works like this;

```
dailyn<-cwoparchive %>%
filter(stationname=="EW2020" %>%
group_by (archivedate) %>%
summarise(ncount=n(),meanlat=mean(latitude),meanlon=mean(longitude)) %>%
collect() %>%
data.frame ()
```

returns this, just what I want:

- archivedate ncount  meanlat   meanlon
- 1   2013-02-06      2 38.82667 -76.79884
- 2   2013-03-19     22 38.82700 -76.79816
- 3   2013-03-21     45 38.82700 -76.79816
- 4   2013-03-22     49 38.82699 -76.79819
- 5   2013-03-24     63 38.82690 -76.79836
- 6   2013-03-27     62 38.82691 -76.79834
- 7   2013-03-28     48 38.82700 -76.79816
- 8   2013-03-29     45 38.82700 -76.79816
- 9  2013-03-30     39 38.82700 -76.79816
- 10  2013-04-01     49 38.82697 -76.79823  etc.

Next I want to know if mornings are sunnier.  But when I do the same thing as above, only replacing that summarise line with this one:

```
summarise(askew=skewness(linterpreted))
```

I get an error message, "Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  function skewness(integer) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts."  Yet the skewness function works fine on the same data in normal, non-grouped data frames.

Comment: Please show a reproducible example and expected output.  Please check if you have also loaded `plyr` package

Comment: thank you for your attention! OK, you'll have to link to my Redshift database.  I'll leave it open 24 hours.  Link thus: cwop_db<-src_postgres(host='my-cluster-cwop-solar.cix687k0xvpq.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com', port='5439', dbname='dev',
                      user='lohancock', password='R0samystica0')
cwoparchive <- tbl(cwop_db, "cwoparchive")

Comment: As I mentioned, you may check whether you load plyr along with dplyr.  If that is the case, this can happen.  Try `dplyr::summarise(stationdata, skewness(radiance))`

Comment: Yes, thank you... but  I do have dplyr loaded.  I added above an example of code that works fine.  It is when I replace mean with skewness that the error appears.

Answer (score 1):

With apologies for bothering everybody, I worked it out. First download, secondly group-by in a follow-on step - this seems irrational but it is necessary, and then summarise on that.

```
stationdata<-cwoparchive %>%
filter(stationname=="EW2020") %>%
collect() %>%
data.frame ()

station_by_day <- group_by(stationdata, archivedate)

skew_by_day <- summarise(station_by_day, count = n(),askew=skewness(linterpreted))
```

produces the ideal result:

- archivedate count      askew

  - (date) (int)      (dbl)
  - 1   2013-02-06     2  0.0000000
  - 2   2013-03-01     5 -0.3755537
  - 3   2013-03-19    22 -0.2498925
  - 4   2013-03-20    38 -0.3328628
  - 5   2013-03-21    45  0.7237873 etc.